# Combining tensorflow inception models/graphs

Tags: tensorflow, training-data

I have done my own training of tensorflow inception a while ago, recently I wanted to add new classes to the original model. However, when I retrain tensorflow it generates a new graph and labels files completely separate from the older one.

Is there a way to combine models? Or do I have to retrain again with the old and new classes?

Answer (score 1):

You have to retrain.  You may be able to use [transfer learning](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_retraining) to do it much faster than you did before.